# Getting error with aws codebuild test reports with testng

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, testng, amazon-codebuild

**Getting following error in AWS codebuild reporting step**

Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: [SurefireReports: [error processing report: [/codebuild/output/src999070/src/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml: expected element type  but have

**Buildspec configuration:**

```
reports:
  SurefireReports:
    files: 
      - "**/*"
    base-directory: 'target/surefire-reports'
    file-format: JunitXml
```